# Can I have a two line text in a select option value

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

Can I have a two line text in a select option value in Salesforce?
Please let me know if there is a work around if not.

thanks
sanjib

Comment: for sure not out of the box, but within VF, it might depend on the browser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746824/can-you-have-multiple-lines-in-an-option-element

Comment: Do you mean with wrapping when displayed on a VF page or when entered in the select option field?

Answer (score 2):

HTML doesn't support line wrapping on options values in a select list. This means that the standard UI also does not support it. It is possible to build one using Visualforce. You might want to start here: [javascript - How can I build a  with multiline option? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368502/how-can-i-build-a-select-with-multiline-option).